# How to write dataframe into hive table simultaneously based on certain value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a scenario in which dataframe as a universal set. Based on that dataframe write into different hive tables based on certain values in the dataframe. But this is acheived through sequential execution. Using filter operation on the universal dataframe and retrieve subset of that dataframe and then  write it into different hive tables.Is it any other way to write into hive table simultaneously using partition methodology on dataframe. That can perform on the universal dataframe to do write operation.

Comment: Can you add what you tried out or example